# Where is the Automation Anywhere registry?

Tags: windows-10, regedit, automationanywhere

I want to uninstall Automation Anywhere from my pc. Therefore I want to romove the registry of Automation Anywhere. If anyone know where is the Automation Anywhere registry file is located then please help me.And I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

For just the client (not the server) installation, you can see below - these folders exist in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

### [image: Here]

If you're on a distributed enterprise installation, you'll likely also find another related entry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Automation Anywhere.

Of course, to get to these entries, `win key + r` > `regedit` and navigate through there.